# Issue with infinite loop in session timeout handler in MVC4 application after idle timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

- Im have an MVC 4 web application.

  - Deployed to my iis7 environment.
  - It uses windows authentication and impersonation.
  - It is set, by company policy, to session timeout after 15 minutes.

This always worked fine in asp.net applications. But i now  have an MVC4 application so instead of using the global.asax and the session_start to determine if session has timed out and re-direct , i have now set up a session expire action filter.

All is working as expected , re-directing when session timesout, until the user leaves the application idle .The idle timeout on the app pool is 20 minutes which i reckon is the issue here.

If my user leave his application open and heads to a meeting which they often do , and the idle timeout is reached , when they come back and attempt to do sometime and the application tries to re-direct on session timeout, i can see in the error logs it gets trapped in a loop , and never re-directs.

Is it too late after the fact (i.e. the idle timeout) to attempt to re-direct ? Previously in asp.net applications(non MVC) i used to always perform this action (i.e. redirect on session timeout) in the session start in the global.asax and it worked a treat. As obviosuly, this event was always hit before the application idle timeout kicked in.

Any help would be appreciated , here is my code for my session handler :

```
 public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework after the action method executes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }

         ///<summary>
         ///Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework before the action method executes.
         ///</summary>
         ///<param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    var sessionStateDetails =(SessionStateSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
                    var sessionCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf(sessionStateDetails.CookieName) >= 0))
                    {
                        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                        {
                            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "SessionTimeout");
                            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");

                            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);

                        }
```

Comment: You could still use Session_Start even in MVC, so what's wrong with doing that?

Comment: Yes session_start still works in MVC4 , and re-directs correctly. However from the blogs ive been reading , I thought using a handler was better practice? Any thoughts ? And this is the reason i went down this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is having a similar issue , I resolved this in the end by using [philpalmieri's](http://philpalmieri.com/2009/09/jquery-session-auto-timeout-with-prompt/) jquery plugin which can be found here on [Github](https://github.com/philpalmieri/jquery-idleTimeout/blob/master/jquery-idleTimeout.js).

By setting it to an idle timeout of 20 minutes , and calling it in this way  , it always re-directs to the session timeout before the app goes into an idle state so my inifinte loop never occurs:

```
function logout() {
    ////session redirect goes here 
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var segment_1 = pathArray[1];
    window.location =  window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + segment_1 + "/Home/SessionTimeout";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var SEC = 1000;
    var MIN = 60 * SEC;
        $(document).idleTimeout({
            inactivity: 20 * MIN,
            noconfirm: 2 * SEC,
            redirect_url: 'javascript:logout()',
            click_reset: true,
            alive_url: '',
            logout_url: ''
        });
});
```

If anyone has any better solution , i'd love to hear it ...